# In Objective C, does creating new class necessarily mean creating a new file for each of the new classes?

Tags: objective-c

I might have just a method or two in each of these classes. Do each of these classes have to be in separate files? 
What the good coding practice here?

Comment: If they are different objects then sure it must be in separate classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545652/341994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't **have to** create a new source file for each class. It's generally a good idea and not really much of a burden, so why wouldn't you? But it's perfectly possible to put multiple `@implementation` blocks for multiple classes in the same source file. If a class is only going to be used in that one source file, its `@interface` block can be there, too. That is, everything about a class can be in the one file along with other classes.

Comment: so, you mean to say the interface & implementation can be in the same file ? In that case, would the file be named .h file ? (even though that file has both the interface and implementation?)

Comment: I also put several very small, closely related classes in one .h and .m file. Even if they're all used in another class. For example a family of criteria used in a rule editor.

Comment: You shouldn't put an implementation in a header file. You *can* put an interface in a source (.m) file, if it's not needed in any other file.

Comment: I put the interfaces of the classes in one header file. The implementations are in the counterpart .m.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to create a new file for each of the new classes. e.g.:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In this way you could still push a new controller. But if you need to implement your custom method, you have to create a new file for the class and add your own method.